# Is it acceptable to solicit volunteer translators for a non-profit project on Esperanto.SE?

Tags: discussion

**Note: I've put all information that might itself be considered unsolicited soliciting into spoiler blocks.** I hope that's alright here on meta. If you don't want to be lured into helping out with the translation, don't hover over those blocks! ;-) **I deliberately didn't (yet) link to the online translation platform used.**

There's a worldwide initiative to provide free programming workshops for women. (Actually there are several. The one I'm talking about is

> [Django Girls](https://djangogirls.org)

)

Their freely licensed and publicly available teaching material

> the [Django Girls tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/)

is originally English, but has been translated to various languages. It isn't yet available in Esperanto, but an Esperanto translation has been begun.

There are only few people working on the translation yet. (So far, we're just 2, working in our spare free time.) We'd like to get more people involved, so we can "crowd-source" the workload, so each contributor won't have to do too much.

I asked myself where I'd find people that

- know both English and Esperanto

  and who
- are likely to have to have some IT experience, maybe even are software developers / programmers themselves (or if not, are at least sufficiently interested in a topic like that)

  and who
- are passionate about learning and teaching

and "on Esperanto Language Stack Exchange" is clearly one of the answers.

As I don't want to spam, I'm wondering **whether it's acceptable to solicit for fellow volunteer translators here on Esperanto.SE**. Obviously, phrased as a question like

> Do you want to help translate this tutorial?

it would be blatantly off-topic because that can only be answered subjectively. (And I can't imagine a question where the soliciting would be appropriate as an answer.) But as I will probably ask questions about Esperanto that come up while translating and as giving the context of those questions might be useful, I guess I could post comments like `"Btw., if you want to help with this translation, join us on <insert online translation platform>."` where they fit.

### Some further context:

The project

> Django Girls

is a **volunteer** initiative, and the organization backing it

> the [Django Girls Foundation](https://djangogirls.org/foundation/)

is a **non-profit** (a registered charity in the UK). While they do sell some merchandise, the course materials, accompanying documentation etc. are all free (as in beer and as in freedom). While I've volunteered at workshops (twice as a coach, another two times as a co-organizer) and have contributed improvements to both, the English original and the German translation, I'm not a member of that foundation. (Though they did recently give me write access on GitHub and proofreader status for German and Esperanto on the online translation platform used. Maintaining the tutorial is mostly a grassroots enterprise, so I doubt most of the involved are members of the foundation themselves.)